# Insertar grafico de Python en Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

cuando quiero insertar un grafico de python en Power BI, me sale el error que les dejo abajo. Lo intente con graficos super basicos y no me deja. Lo intente en otras computadoras y tampoco. Soy nuevo en todo esto, tendrá que ver con las librerias instaladas?

ERROR:

```
Error Message:
ÞУŧћøñ ŝ¢ѓĭρť έřґσŕ.
C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\PythonScriptWrapper_cc77317b-54cc-452e-af2c-a1151036f59c\PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, uuid, matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\st1capelda\.conda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
```

Comment: `ÞУŧћøñ ŝ¢ѓĭρť έřґσŕ.`?? que pasa ahi?

Comment: Así sale sale en el mensaje de error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yo habia instalado python y las libreras con anaconda, por eso power BI no me dejaba visualizar los graficos. Hay que instalar python por separado

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.